# In Rails 3 how could I create a db only contact form not using scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, scaffolding

New to rails 3

I would like to create a contact form that people fill out, its saved to the db and then a thank you page comes up.

I would like to do this without scaffold so I can learn better, and I figure that by doing it this way it would be easer to setup so that people cannot try and look at other people's entries by modifying the url.

ideally it would keep their state in the session or cookie so that they would end up on the thanks page if they came back.

Have been trying to do this for about 3 days and reading/googling tons, but between the new routes redirect_to controller stuff in rails3 havn't managed to figure it out.

**Routes.rb**

```
Contact::Application.routes.draw do
resources :contactees, :only => [:new, :create]
# to make sure crud doesn't have the routest I don't want

get 'contactees/submitted'

root :to => 'contactees#new'
```

**contactees_controller.rb**

```
ContacteesController < ApplicationControler

def share
end

def new
  @contactee = Contactee.new
end

def create
  @contactee = Contactee.new(params[:contactee])
    if @contactee.save
      redirect_to submitted_contactee
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
end

end
```

**Views**

```
contactees
  _form.html.erb
  new.html.erb
  submitted.html.erb
```

Comment: Post some of your best guess code, you're more likely going to get feedback on what you're doing wrong rather than someone writing all the code out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the submitted route, you don't need it. Perhaps something like this?

```
def new
  render :submitted if session[:contacted]
end

def create
  @contactee = Contactee.new(params[:contactee])
    if @contactee.save
      session[:contacted] = true
      render :submitted
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
end
```